# How to convert multiple Objects to an Array [] of key-value pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to display a table in react-native but it requires the data to be in arrays,

the API returns an object with all the rows, so far I have managed to convert only if there is a single row and doesn't convert the second row if its available.

Api from the server

```
0: {title: "Transportation", amount: "100"}
1: {title: "Food", amount: "50"}
```

what I need is

```
0:["Transportation", "100"]
1:["Food", "50"]
```

this is my code

```
const state = this.state;
let table = this.state.payments;
console.log(table);
const tableD = Object.keys(table[0]).map((key, index) => table[0][key]);
console.log(tableD);
const tableData = [tableD];
console.log(tableData);
return (
    <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: theme.colors.primary}}>
    <Row data={state.tableHead} style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: theme.colors.gray2}} textStyle={{margin: 6}}/>
    <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={{ margin: 6, }}/>
    </Table>
)
```

this is the error that I get

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {title, amount}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are telling it to change just the first (index 0) value in the array.

First of all, you need to use Object.values as said by matevzpoljianc, after that you need to loop trough all your array.

So it would be:

```
let table = this.state.payments;  
const tableD = this.state.payments.map(item=>Object.values(item))
console.log(tableD);
```

Now you would've your array of arrays.

EDIT.

If you server is responding with an object that has numbers as keys then what I've wrote won't work, but you can simply hotfix it to:

```
 let table = this.state.payments;
 const tableD = Object.values(this.state.payments).map(item=>Object.values(item))
 console.log(tableD);
```

Comment: worked like a charm with a single tweak, thanks
final edit

let table = this.state.payments;  //your array of objects
 const tableD = Object.values(this.state.payments[0]).map(item=>Object.values(item))
 console.log(tableD);

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.values(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) function to get just values.

If you need key, value pairs you can use [Object.entries(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, here's how:

```
let table = this.state.payments.slice(); //use .slice() to create a copy.
for(row in table){
   table[row] = Object.values(table[row]); //direct transformation
}
console.log(table); //table is your formatted table.
```